# Bundling support in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

Is bundling supported in shiny? By bundling I mean combining multiple CSS, JS files into a single file. Fewer files means fewer HTTP requests and that can improve first page load performance. It is mainly to improve request load time. Challenge I have with shiny is I am using multiple packages (highcharter, DT, shinywidgets etc) for app and every package has its own CSS and JS file.